# grpc on PHP Socket Closed

Tags: php, grpc

I am encountering a "Socket Closed" with status `UNAVAILABLE(14)` with PHP client, the server is written in golang.

The same code works only in docker using the php-fpm image `php:7.0.6-fpm` via browser (CLI fails with the same error), but fails everywhere else including on my Mac with natively installed PHP(7.3.4). I have run a testing Golang client and it works perfectly on the same machines.

I have filled an issue on github as suggested by [Zhouyihai Ding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783516/grpc-on-php-socket-closed#comment98242438_55783516) https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18826

here is the gRPC extension trace output `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=all`, it's truncated due to this posting limit.

```
D0421 14:41:39.308255868    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 2 -> 3 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:595]
I0421 14:41:39.308262647    1321 chttp2_transport.cc:2792]   set connectivity_state=4
I0421 14:41:39.308287703    1321 connectivity_state.cc:164]  SET: 0x7f7668005350 client_transport: READY --> SHUTDOWN [close_transport] error=0x2b8a660 {"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
I0421 14:41:39.308298675    1321 connectivity_state.cc:190]  NOTIFY: 0x7f7668005350 client_transport: 0x7f7668003f10
D0421 14:41:39.308305766    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 3 -> 4 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.cc:192]
I0421 14:41:39.308313172    1321 timer_generic.cc:467]       TIMER 0x7f76680069f8: CANCEL pending=true
I0421 14:41:39.308320240    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f7668006840 last=3
D0421 14:41:39.308328283    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 4 -> 5 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:623]
I0421 14:41:39.308335236    1321 ev_posix.cc:272]            (polling-api) fd_shutdown(3)
I0421 14:41:39.308341630    1321 ev_posix.cc:273]            (fd-trace) fd_shutdown(3)
D0421 14:41:39.308348627    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 5 -> 6 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.cc:383]
E0421 14:41:39.308357648    1321 lockfree_event.cc:164]      LockfreeEvent::SetShutdown: 0x7f7668001bd8 curr=(nil) err={"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
D0421 14:41:39.308382658    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 6 -> 7 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.cc:387]
E0421 14:41:39.308394812    1321 lockfree_event.cc:164]      LockfreeEvent::SetShutdown: 0x7f7668001be0 curr=0x2 err={"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
D0421 14:41:39.308404404    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 7 -> 8 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.cc:388]
E0421 14:41:39.308412536    1321 lockfree_event.cc:164]      LockfreeEvent::SetShutdown: 0x7f7668001be8 curr=(nil) err={"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
D0421 14:41:39.308422106    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 8 -> 7 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.cc:390]
I0421 14:41:39.308442439    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x2b899d0 last=1
D0421 14:41:39.308450976    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 7 -> 6 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:629]
I0421 14:41:39.308458966    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1099 unref 6 -> 5 writing
I0421 14:41:39.308466229    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=5
D0421 14:41:39.308481951    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x7f7668003f10: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:317]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.cc:192]
I0421 14:41:39.308490232    1321 subchannel.cc:359]          Connected subchannel 0x7f7668000c00 of subchannel 0x7f7668002260 has gone into SHUTDOWN. Attempting to reconnect.
D0421 14:41:39.308498220    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 6 -> 7 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:370]
I0421 14:41:39.308517014    1321 connectivity_state.cc:164]  SET: 0x7f7668002338 subchannel: READY --> TRANSIENT_FAILURE [reflect_child] error=0x2b8a660 {"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
I0421 14:41:39.308538992    1321 connectivity_state.cc:190]  NOTIFY: 0x7f7668002338 subchannel: 0x7f7668004a38
D0421 14:41:39.308547025    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 7 -> 8 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.cc:192]
D0421 14:41:39.308554347    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 8 -> 9 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:374]
I0421 14:41:39.308563025    1321 connectivity_state.cc:164]  SET: 0x7f7668002358 subchannel: READY --> TRANSIENT_FAILURE [reflect_child] error=0x2b8a660 {"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}
D0421 14:41:39.308573343    1321 subchannel.cc:342]          SUBCHANNEL: 0x7f7668002260   WEAK_UNREF 0x10003 -> 0x10002 [state_watcher]
D0421 14:41:39.308580661    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x7f7668003f10 finished
D0421 14:41:39.308587536    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 9 -> 8 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.cc:46]
D0421 14:41:39.308595080    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x7f7668004a38: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:450]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.cc:192]
I0421 14:41:39.308602808    1321 ev_posix.cc:381]            (polling-api) pollset_set_del_pollset_set(0xdeafbeef, 0xdeafbeef)
D0421 14:41:39.308610256    1321 subchannel.cc:467]          SUBCHANNEL: 0x7f7668002260   WEAK_UNREF 0x10002 -> 0x10001 [external_state_watcher+done]
D0421 14:41:39.308617403    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 8 -> 9 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc:469]
I0421 14:41:39.308624445    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f76680015c0 last=1
D0421 14:41:39.308631697    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x7f7668004a38 finished
D0421 14:41:39.308638789    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 9 -> 8 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.cc:46]
I0421 14:41:39.308646147    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308653248    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668000f20 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f7668006840
I0421 14:41:39.308660877    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:2624 unref 5 -> 4 bdp_ping
I0421 14:41:39.308670347    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=3
I0421 14:41:39.308677383    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308684248    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668003300 maybe_finish_one n=0x2b899d0
I0421 14:41:39.308691279    1321 resource_quota.cc:544]      RU shutdown 0x7f76680037a0
I0421 14:41:39.308699455    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f7668006950 last=1
I0421 14:41:39.308706307    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f76680069a0 last=3
I0421 14:41:39.308714549    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668003300 finish old_state=3
I0421 14:41:39.308721638    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308728712    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x2b896b0 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f76680015c0
I0421 14:41:39.308739017    1321 subchannel_list.h:442]      [pick_first 0x7f76680010b0] subchannel list 0x7f7668001560 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x7f7668002260): connectivity changed: state=TRANSIENT_FAILURE, error={"created":"@1555854099.307546922","description":"Delayed close due to in-progress write","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":587,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307184724","description":"Endpoint read failed","file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2500,"occurred_during_write":0,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1555854099.307074894","description":"Socket closed","fd":3,"file":"/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc","file_line":479,"grpc_status":14,"target_address":"ipv4:192.168.20.211:5554"}]}]}, shutting_down=0
D0421 14:41:39.308750313    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8a660: 8 -> 9 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.h:466]
I0421 14:41:39.308765853    1321 pick_first.cc:455]          Pick First 0x7f76680010b0 connectivity changed for selected subchannel
I0421 14:41:39.308773541    1321 connectivity_state.cc:164]  SET: 0x7f7668001118 pick_first: READY --> IDLE [selected_changed+reresolve] error=(nil) "No Error"
I0421 14:41:39.308780856    1321 connectivity_state.cc:190]  NOTIFY: 0x7f7668001118 pick_first: 0x7f7668000c60
I0421 14:41:39.308787975    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f7668000c60 last=3
I0421 14:41:39.308795744    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f7668001338 last=5
I0421 14:41:39.308804391    1321 lb_policy.cc:76]            pick_first 0x7f76680010b0: scheduling re-resolution closure with error="No Error".
I0421 14:41:39.308812329    1321 subchannel_list.h:370]      [pick_first 0x7f76680010b0] subchannel list 0x7f7668001560 index 0 of 1 (subchannel 0x7f7668002260): stopping connectivity watch
I0421 14:41:39.308820571    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          pick_first:0x7f7668001568 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/subchannel_list.h:379 unref 2 -> 1 connectivity_watch
D0421 14:41:39.308828550    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 9 -> 8 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc:502]
D0421 14:41:39.308836366    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 8 -> 7 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/combiner.cc:269]
I0421 14:41:39.308843720    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x2b896b0 finish old_state=7
I0421 14:41:39.308850909    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308859510    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x2b896b0 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f7668000c60
I0421 14:41:39.308866652    1321 request_routing.cc:429]     request_router=0x2b89508: lb_policy=0x7f76680010b0 state changed to IDLE
I0421 14:41:39.308874329    1321 request_routing.cc:606]     request_router=0x2b89508: setting connectivity state to IDLE
I0421 14:41:39.308882521    1321 connectivity_state.cc:164]  SET: 0x2b895e0 request_router: READY --> IDLE [lb_changed] error=(nil) "No Error"
I0421 14:41:39.308890918    1321 connectivity_state.cc:116]  CONWATCH: 0x7f7668001118 pick_first: from IDLE [cur=IDLE] notify=0x7f7668000c60
I0421 14:41:39.308898022    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x2b896b0 finish old_state=5
I0421 14:41:39.308905537    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x2b896b0 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308912598    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x2b896b0 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f7668001338
I0421 14:41:39.308919826    1321 request_routing.cc:488]     request_router=0x2b89508: started name re-resolving
D0421 14:41:39.308927348    1321 dns_resolver.cc:255]        In cooldown from last resolution (from 39 ms ago). Will resolve again in 961 ms
I0421 14:41:39.308935981    1321 ref_counted.h:98]           resolver_refcount:0x2b89b48 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.cc:264 ref 1 -> 2 next_resolution_timer_cooldown
I0421 14:41:39.308945248    1321 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x2b89bf8: SET 961 now 44 call 0x2b89c30[0x7f766eb842c0]
I0421 14:41:39.308952971    1321 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 0 with queue_deadline_cap=1001 => is_first_timer=true
I0421 14:41:39.308961158    1321 timer_generic.cc:423]         .. old shard min_deadline=1002
I0421 14:41:39.308968382    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x2b896b0 finish old_state=3
I0421 14:41:39.308976605    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.308983950    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668000f20 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f7668006950
I0421 14:41:39.308993231    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:3072 unref 4 -> 3 benign_reclaimer
I0421 14:41:39.309001756    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=5
I0421 14:41:39.309009029    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.309016290    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668000f20 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f76680069a0
I0421 14:41:39.309024078    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:3103 unref 3 -> 2 destructive_reclaimer
I0421 14:41:39.309032311    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=3
I0421 14:41:39.309039183    1321 ev_epoll1_linux.cc:990]      .. remove worker
I0421 14:41:39.309046461    1321 ev_posix.cc:323]            (polling-api) pollset_work(0x2b85880, 9223372036854775807) end
D0421 14:41:39.309054102    1321 transport.cc:59]            CALL_STACK 0x2b9d9a0:0x2b9cfa0 UNREF 2->1 completion
I0421 14:41:39.309062209    1321 completion_queue.cc:1295]   RETURN_EVENT[0x2b85740]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x2b9cfa0 OK
D0421 14:41:39.309070351    1321 completion_queue.cc:1296]   CQ:0x2b85740 unref 4 -> 3 pluck
I0421 14:41:39.309081223    1321 metadata_array.cc:34]       grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffd8faa82f0)
I0421 14:41:39.309088709    1321 metadata_array.cc:34]       grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffd8faa8310)
I0421 14:41:39.309095533    1321 metadata_array.cc:34]       grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffd8faa8330)
I0421 14:41:39.309102250    1321 metadata_array.cc:34]       grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffd8faa8350)
I0421 14:41:39.309113576    1321 call.cc:562]                grpc_call_unref(c=0x2b9cfa0)
I0421 14:41:39.309122525    1321 call_combiner.cc:215]       call_combiner=0x2b9cfb0: setting notify_on_cancel=(nil)
D0421 14:41:39.309130167    1321 transport.cc:59]            CALL_STACK 0x2b9d9a0:0x2b9cfa0 UNREF 1->0 destroy
D0421 14:41:39.309138867    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x2b9d9a8: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:131]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:80]
D0421 14:41:39.309147505    1321 call.cc:534]                CQ:0x2b85740 unref 3 -> 2 bind
D0421 14:41:39.309154996    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8ade0: 1 -> 0 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc:542]
D0421 14:41:39.309164599    1321 transport.cc:59]            CALL_STACK 0x2b9e240:0x2b9e1c0 UNREF 1->0 
D0421 14:41:39.309172860    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x2b9d9a8 finished
D0421 14:41:39.309180182    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x2b9e248: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:131]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:80]
I0421 14:41:39.309188932    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x2b9efe8 last=1
D0421 14:41:39.309197371    1321 transport.cc:59]            CLIENT_SUBCHANNEL 0x7f7668003b10:0x7f7668003b10 UNREF 1->0 connected_subchannel_dtor
D0421 14:41:39.309205678    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x2b9e248 finished
D0421 14:41:39.309212951    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x7f7668003b18: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:131]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/transport.cc:80]
D0421 14:41:39.309221148    1321 client_authority_filter.cc:116] ELM UNREF:0x7f7668003c70:2->1: ':authority' = '192.168.20.211:5554'
D0421 14:41:39.309230359    1321 http_client_filter.cc:584]  ELM UNREF:0x7f7668003df0:2->1: 'user-agent' = 'grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gold)'
I0421 14:41:39.309238105    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x2b8a530 last=3
D0421 14:41:39.309245500    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x7f7668003b18 finished
I0421 14:41:39.309252745    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.309261348    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668000f20 maybe_finish_one n=0x2b9efe8
D0421 14:41:39.309268943    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8b9e0: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:723]
I0421 14:41:39.309277016    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:733 unref 2 -> 1 stream
I0421 14:41:39.309284499    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=5
D0421 14:41:39.309292056    1321 exec_ctx.cc:34]             running closure 0x2b9d920: created [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc:548]: scheduled [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:734]
D0421 14:41:39.309302088    1321 transport.cc:59]            CLIENT_CHANNEL 0x2b89478:0x2b89410 UNREF 5->4 call
D0421 14:41:39.309310277    1321 exec_ctx.cc:43]             closure 0x2b9d920 finished
I0421 14:41:39.309317464    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668000f20 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.309325506    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668000f20 maybe_finish_one n=0x2b8a530
D0421 14:41:39.309333046    1321 error.cc:337]               0x2b8fdf0 create [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:561]
D0421 14:41:39.309342045    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8fdf0: 1 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:576]
D0421 14:41:39.309349820    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:2417]
D0421 14:41:39.309357365    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8fdf0: 1 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:577]
D0421 14:41:39.309364833    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8fdf0: 2 -> 3 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309372117    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 3 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309379714    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8fdf0: 2 -> 3 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309387043    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 3 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309394445    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b8fdf0: 2 -> 3 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309401709    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 3 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309409005    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1710]
D0421 14:41:39.309416459    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 1 -> 0 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:629]
I0421 14:41:39.309424353    1321 ref_counted.h:139]          chttp2_refcount:0x7f7668005008 /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:564 unref 1 -> 0 destroy
D0421 14:41:39.309433219    1321 tcp_posix.cc:402]           TCP unref 0x7f76680033f0 : destroy 1 -> 0
I0421 14:41:39.309440686    1321 ev_posix.cc:265]            (polling-api) fd_orphan(3, (nil), (nil), tcp_unref_orphan)
I0421 14:41:39.309447600    1321 ev_posix.cc:266]            (fd-trace) grpc_fd_orphan, fd:3 closed
D0421 14:41:39.309463319    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 7 -> 6 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.cc:79]
D0421 14:41:39.309472858    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 6 -> 5 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.cc:79]
D0421 14:41:39.309480206    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 5 -> 4 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.cc:79]
I0421 14:41:39.309487633    1321 combiner.cc:167]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_execute c=0x7f7668003978 last=1
D0421 14:41:39.309496202    1321 error.cc:337]               0x2b8fdf0 create [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_posix.cc:350]
D0421 14:41:39.309503878    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 1 -> 0 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/buffer_list.h:152]
D0421 14:41:39.309512868    1321 hpack_encoder.cc:612]       ELM UNREF:0x7f7668003df0:1->0: 'user-agent' = 'grpc-c/7.0.0 (linux; chttp2; gold)'
D0421 14:41:39.309521476    1321 hpack_encoder.cc:612]       ELM UNREF:0x7f7668003c70:1->0: ':authority' = '192.168.20.211:5554'
D0421 14:41:39.309529415    1321 error.cc:337]               0x2b8fdf0 create [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:175]
D0421 14:41:39.309538158    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8fdf0: 1 -> 0 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:179]
D0421 14:41:39.309546169    1321 hpack_table.cc:196]         ELM UNREF:0x7f76680048b0:1->0: 'grpc-message' = ''
D0421 14:41:39.309555743    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 4 -> 3 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/transport/connectivity_state.cc:72]
D0421 14:41:39.309564113    1321 chttp2_transport.cc:198]    C:0x7f7668000f20 UNREF 1 --> 0 chttp2_transport
I0421 14:41:39.309571264    1321 combiner.cc:103]            C:0x7f7668000f20 really_destroy old_state=3
D0421 14:41:39.309579633    1321 error.cc:337]               0x2b90f00 create [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:201]
D0421 14:41:39.309587524    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b90f00: 1 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309594933    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b90f00: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309602435    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b90f00: 1 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309609772    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b90f00: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309617273    1321 error.cc:127]               0x2b90f00: 1 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1707]
D0421 14:41:39.309624731    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b90f00: 2 -> 1 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/closure.h:222]
D0421 14:41:39.309632026    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b90f00: 1 -> 0 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:1710]
D0421 14:41:39.309640946    1321 error.cc:175]               0x2b8a660: 3 -> 2 [/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc:211]
I0421 14:41:39.309648774    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668000f20 finish old_state=2
I0421 14:41:39.309655775    1321 combiner.cc:94]             C:0x7f7668000f20 really_destroy
I0421 14:41:39.309663228    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=0
I0421 14:41:39.309670350    1321 combiner.cc:254]            C:0x7f7668003300 maybe_finish_one n=0x7f7668003978
I0421 14:41:39.309678217    1321 combiner.cc:340]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_execute_finally c=0x7f7668003220; ac=0x7f7668003300
I0421 14:41:39.309685587    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668003300 finish old_state=5
I0421 14:41:39.309692734    1321 combiner.cc:231]            C:0x7f7668003300 grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx contended=0 exec_ctx_ready_to_finish=1 time_to_execute_final_list=1
I0421 14:41:39.309700872    1321 combiner.cc:278]            C:0x7f7668003300 execute_final[0] c=0x7f7668003220
D0421 14:41:39.309708252    1321 resource_quota.cc:666]      C:0x7f7668003300 UNREF 1 --> 0 resource_quota
I0421 14:41:39.309715385    1321 combiner.cc:103]            C:0x7f7668003300 really_destroy old_state=3
I0421 14:41:39.309722329    1321 combiner.cc:296]            C:0x7f7668003300 finish old_state=2
I0421 14:41:39.309729147    1321 combiner.cc:94]             C:0x7f7668003300 really_destroy
```

Version information:

```
PHP: 7.0.6 / 7.3.4
grpc php extension: 1.19.0
protobuf php version: 3.7.1
golang grpc version: google.golang.org/grpc v1.19.0
```

Comment: Can you please create an issue to the grpc/grpc repo?
Is UNAVAILABLE(14) returned immediately? Does previews grpc PHP version work?

Comment: yes both protobuf and grpc versions show normally.